# Apache: Difference between <Proxy> and ProxyPass

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-proxy

What is the difference between a `ProxyPass` directive:

```
ProxyPass         /     http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /     http://localhost:8080/
```

And a `<Proxy>` directive:

```
<Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

In Apache configuration files?

I often see these two in the same `virtualhost` section, an I am not sure what is the difference.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this is a valid and clear question.

Comment: Probably nobody knows that, but the only we can do against this to compensate for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `ProxyPass` [(link)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive, you define  a proxy in the first place. The `<proxy ...>` [(link)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy) section can contain processing directives for the proxied content. This is something you can learn yourself by just reading the docs, hence the downvotes.

Comment: Many questions can be answered by "just reading the docs". I think that if the question is useful for others and uses accurate technical terms, it should not be downvoted.

Comment: I disagree. Reading the docs is the professional first step. If this answers the question, it's not useful. Also "Does not show any research effort" is one of the principal downvote reasons, it's even the "alt text" for the downvote link/arrow.

Comment: Is there a link to specific place which answers this question? If so, I think you are right. If not, and understanding this issue requires synthesising a few sources, I think that the question is valid.

Comment: +1 I disagree with your downvote, but thanks for the answer.